# Linux Socket file descriptor with threads

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, sockets, stdthread

consider following situation: One thread (lets call it A) initialises, sets socket state with `listen()` and then wait with `accept()`. Connection arrives to A socket, `accept()` returns valid fd. New thread (B) is created (using `std::thread`), and acquired fd is passed to a callable object witch runs in thread B. Reading (using `read()`) for fd fails and `errno` is set to `9 EBADFD`. Thread A calls `join()` on B. When B is not spawned and fd is used (still via same callable object) read completes without failure. Why? Below is some code to illustrate this situation.

```
BaseFun::BaseFun(char* bufferAdr, int socket):
    socket_fd(socket)
    buffer(bufferAdr)
{}

BaseFun::~BaseFun()
{
    close(socket_fd);
}

char* BaseFun::buffer_read()
{
    if(read(socket_fd, buffer, BUFF_SIZE-1) < 0) {
        std::cout<<"ERROR while READ\n"<<"ERRNO: "<<errno<<"\n"<<"FD: "<<socket_fd<<"\n";
    }
    return buffer;
}

DisplayMsgFun::DisplayMsgFun(char* buffer, int socket) :
    BaseFun(buffer, socket)
{}

void DisplayMsgFunFun::operator()()
{
    std::cout<<"Message:\n\t"<<buffer_read()<<"\nEND\n";
}
```

Snippet where above is called:

```
void Server::server_run()
{
    sockaddr_in client_addr;
    socklen_t c_len = sizeof(client_addr);

    client_fd = accept(sock_fd, (sockaddr*)&client_addr, &c_len);
    DisplayMsgFun dm(server_buffers->front().data(), client_fd);
    std::thread job(dm);
    job.join();
}
```

And `main()`

```
int main()
{
    Server srv(PORT);
    if (srv.server_create()) {
        std::cout << "Server bind!\n";
        srv.server_run();
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Bind fail! ERRNO: "<<errno<<"\n";
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but why create a thread if the next thing you do is just to wait for it? I assume you do something else between the thread creation and the `join` call? Maybe the problem is *that* part (that you don't show us)?

Comment: I'd be interested to see how you fix this.  I know enough C++ to spot the problem (per my answer), but not to fix it.   I wonder if just writing `std::thread job(std::ref(dm))` would be sufficient.

Comment: @Alnitak I've run quick test and `std::ref()` solves problem. But I guess that will not be sufficient in "large scale", or when I will try to get rid off this `join()` call.

Comment: Right, because you have to ensure that `dm` doesn't get destroyed when it goes out of scope when your `server_run` function finishes while the thread is still trying to use that object.  Hmm...

Comment: It seems to me like you need to implement a move constructor, such that when you call `std::thread job(dm)` only the new instance of the object maintains the file descriptor (and gains responsibility for closing it) and the original learns that it no longer has to (perhaps by setting `socket_fd` to a negative value to signal that)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You appear to be passing a *copy* of the `DisplayMsgFun` object to the `std::thread` constructor, which means that the original copy gets destroyed, automatically calling `::close` per your destructor.